# Im trying to create a a code that count numbers divisible by 9 by putting numbers into an array and count the numbers in it

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, counting, integer-division

Im trying to create a a code that count numbers divisible by 9 by putting numbers into  an array and count the numbers in it but it only prints 1 instead of the number of numbers divisible by 9 please help me i want to use array to count those numbers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b,i;
    int numbers[]={i};
    cin >>a>>b;
    for (i=a; i<=b; i++)
        if (i%9==0){
            cout << sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);
        }        
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: what do you expect to gain from printing `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])` ?!?

Comment: why do you think you need an array? `int numbers[]={i};` has only a single element. Actually it is undefined behavior, because `i` is used uninitialzed

Comment: I thought it would count the number of numbers divisible by 9 in the array and print out the numbers can you help me please it print out "1" equal the numbers that devisible by 9

Comment: Do you *have* to use an array  (for learning porpuses) or do you just need to calculate the answer?

Comment: i want to use array for my learning porpuses please help me

Comment: The idiom of `sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);` computes the size of the entire array in bytes, divided by the size of the first element in bytes, which will equal the number of elements in the array (since all elements are the same size in an array), commonly referred to as the _length_ of the array.  In your case this will equal `1`, and will not change.  The length of an array does not change at run-time; those sizes are determined at compile time..

Comment: Is there anyways to count those numbers by using array? I like to take it as a challenge

Comment: @ĐoànTấnNam challenges like "calculate X using Y" make no sense most of the time. I mean try to compute those numbers using `std::variant` what does that mean?

Comment: Thank you but my teacher want me to count the numbers instead of printing those is there anyways to count them i was first thinking about using array because sizeof can count the number in the array

Comment: There are many ways, but the most important thing that should be learned is that, in C++, arrays are statically sized (their size must be known at compile time), while containers like `std::vector` can grow. Also, there are [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that can be used. Even better, *don't* use an array or a container when a simple calculation can yield you the correct result without wasting memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code are you adding numbers to the array. Anyhow, it is not possible to add elements to arrays, because they are of fixed size. Your array has a single element.

Moreover, `int numbers[]={i};` is undefined, because `i` has not been initialized.

Further, it is not clear what is the purpose of `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])` in your code. `sizeof(numbers)` is the size of a single `int` because the array has a single element. `sizeof(numbers[0])` is the size of a single `int` as well. Hence the result is `1` always. (Its a compile time constant btw.)

If you want to count how many numbers fullfil some condition you best use a counter and print its value after the loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a,b;

    cin >> a >> b;
    unsigned counter = 0;
    for (int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
        if (i%9==0){
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    std::cout << counter;
}
```

---

> i want to use array for my learning porpuses please help me

You chose the wrong example to train working with arrays, because as already mentioned, arrays have fixed size. It is an opportunity to learn about `std::vector`. You can add elements to a `std::vector` at runtime and query its size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    int a,b;
    std::vector<int> by9divisables;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
        if (i%9==0) {
            by9divisables.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    std::cout << by9divisables.size();
}
```

However, other than to see how `std::vector` is working, the vector has no place in this code. As you can see above, the result can be obtained without it.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
int numbers[]={i};
```

declares an array with only one element and initializes it with an indeterminate value stored in the variable `i` because the variable `i` was not initialized.

The body of this if statement

```
    if (i%9==0){
        cout << sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);
    }
```

does not make a sense because it always outputs the number of elements in the array `numbers` that has only one element. But according to the description of the assignment you have to place numbers divisible by `9` into the array.

As the user can enter arbitrary values for the variables `a` and `b` then it means that you need a variable length array. However variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. Instead you should use the standard container `std::vector`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    const int divisor = 9; 

    std::cout << "Enter two integer numbers: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    if ( b < a ) std::swap( a, b );

    for ( int i = a; not ( b < i ); ++i )
    {
        if ( i % divisor == 0 ) numbers.push_back( i );
    }

    std::cout << "There are " << numbers.size() 
              << " numbers divisible by " << divisor
              << " in the range [" << a << ", " << b << "]\n";

    if ( numbers.size() != 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "They are ";

        for ( const auto &n : numbers )
        {
            std::cout << n << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    } 
}
```

Comment: getting fancy? `not ( b < i)` =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing one's for each element found because your array only has one element in it!

Print i instead like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a,b,i;
    //int numbers[]={i};
    cin >>a>>b;
    for (i=a; i<=b; i++)
    {
        if (i%9==0)
        {
            cout << "i: " << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```